# "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" while importing data from Excel sheet to SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I want to import an Excel sheet into SQL Server using C#
My Office version is Microsoft Office 2013
Windows version : Windows 10
I tried to download this tool
[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)
and change CPU to x86 but nothing changed
This is my code

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            of1.Filter = "xls|*.xlsx";
            if ((of1.ShowDialog()) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                imagepath = of1.FileName; //image path
                textBox1.Text = imagepath.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void loadbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ssqltable = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
            string myexceldataquery = "select * from ["+ ssqltable + "$]";
            try
            {
                string sexcelconnectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Work\Bioxcell\UCB.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel12.0Xml;HDR=YES;";
                string ssqlconnectionstring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Bioxcell;Integrated Security=True";
                OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
                OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
                oledbconn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                }

                oledbconn.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Error message : `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine.  Install this:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

That should fix your problem!!